# C# pointer to another function in a different assembly

Tags: vb.net, function, delegates

I would like an ergonomic way to declare local pointers to methods in other assemblies. For example, I have a very useful function written in VB.Net (yes, I know it's VB but it's historical and in a widely used assembly) which is:

```
    Public Function IIN(oValue As Object, ParamArray oValues() As Object) As Boolean
        Dim iA As Integer

        For iA = oValues.GetLowerBound(0) To oValues.GetUpperBound(0)
            If oValue = oValues(iA) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False
    End Function
```

which is inspried from the SQL IN keyword. It's very useful. It allows me to use statements like this:

```
if (Dolphin.modGeneral.IIN(oResult.DataType.Code, "BIGINT", "DECIMAL", "FLOAT", "INT", "MONEY", "SMALLINT", "TINYINT"))
{
```

which is far more concise than:

```
if ((oResult.DataType.Code == "BIGINT") || 
    (oResult.DataType.Code == "DECIMAL") || 
    (oResult.DataType.Code == "FLOAT") || 
    (oResult.DataType.Code == "INT") || 
    (oResult.DataType.Code == "MONEY") || 
    (oResult.DataType.Code == "SMALLINT") || 
    (oResult.DataType.Code == "TINYINT"))
{
```

I'd very much like to make this more concise so that I can do this:

```
if (IIN(oResult.DataType.Code, "BIGINT", "DECIMAL", "FLOAT", "INT", "MONEY", "SMALLINT", "TINYINT"))
{
```

which removes the assembly reference, but I'd like to do this without declaring the entire function locally.

I used to be able to do something in C (many years ago), which for this example would equate to something like:

```
#define IIN Dolphin.modGeneral.IIN
```

which was dealt with by the compiler and was effectively a pre-compilation text substitution. However, in C# I have to do something like this:

```
        private delegate bool delIIN(object oValue, params object[] oValues);
        private delIIN IIN;
```

and then in all the constructors for the class I also need to have an assignment statement thus:

```
        IIN = Dolphin.modGeneral.IIN;
```

After a rather convoluted setup, my actual question is: is there a more concise way I can declare shortcuts to functions like this, more like the C define statement rather than having to declare a delegate type, a delegate function and then having to assign a value to the delegate function in all the constructors?

Comment: Most collection types in C# have a Contains method which does exactly what you're doing here and _much_ more efficiently. There is Array.Exists method you can use on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare that you want to include all members of a static class like this:

```
using static Dolphin.modGeneral;
```

However you might find it useful to consider the efficiency of any of your existing methods and create some newer ones. For example:

```
public static bool IIN(this string value, params string[] values)
{
    return values.Contains(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I completely take your point about efficiency. I get an error with the ```using static Dolphin.modGeneral``` though, which is: "Identifier expected; 'static' is a keyword".